# PXE-M0F exiting intel boot agent

Tags: windows, windows-server-2016, pxe-boot

I have a VS running Windows Server 2016 Standard hired to [hetzner.com](https://hetzner.com/).

I use this server to run just one single application: Jarvee. What i mean is i don't make any modifications or special setups over the server, just install and run the application.

Some times for any reason, a used to lose the connection with the server, which forced me to restart it. Last time i restarted it, the server didn't load Windows. They (hetzner) provided me KVM console and i could see the following error:

> PXE-M0F exiting intel boot agent
>   [see screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8mMqf.png)

I've been looking and trying solutions from the internet, but nothing solves my problem. I have 0 knowledge about servers administration and i asked hetzner to solve this problem but they told me that just support hardware issues, that why i came here. I hope you can help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Server is trying to automatically boot from `local disk,` for some reason it fails then next it tries booting a `Network boot` (PXE) it also fails (not a PXE environment available) then the Boot agent quits after not finding a suitable media to boot from.
Something wrong happened to your VS bootable `local disk`

Comment: Thanks @Pat. Through the KVM console, i could boot a WS image, and try to repair windows, which let me open a cmd. From here i can access all my files, so i guess the local disk is reachable. isn't it?

Comment: reaching the local disk data does not mean that the disk is "bootable". You should perform a proper Windows repair; that it will solve the problem with your non booting disk.

Comment: Thanks @Pat, can you give any clue about where to start?

Comment: You should ask hetzner.com how to boot a Windows repair disk and just run it.

Comment: They don't support any software issues. I'll keep trying! Thanks so much!